# How to Conditionally create rows in grouped data

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr, lubridate

I have a large df of detection data, and I am trying to calculate the duration of time the tags were detected on any given day for each tag. I have code worked out to determine any time there is a gap in detections >1 hour, sum the seconds in that gap, and then subtract it from 24 hours to get the time total detection time. The problem is the gaps at the beginning and end of each day aren't being counted. If tags weren't detected around midnight, the gap spanning midnight is miscounted. I'd like to add a row for each tag each day its detected at 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 so that I can use the code I currently have, and have it count those gaps.

Additionally, my code is using the lag function to count gaps based on the day before it, but there are some days with no detections, creating weird numbers. I'd like to expand the df to fill in each missing date with 2 detections, 1 at 00:00:00 and 1 at 23:59:59, so I can count days where there are no detections as well. There are multiple tags and the df is massive (>3000000 detections) so I'd like to do this in dplyr without splitting each tag into its own df

I know this is confusing, I will post sample data and code I've tried below. Please feel free to send questions, its difficult to explain this without seeing it!

data:

```
structure(list(motusTagID = c(32658L, 32658L, 32658L, 32658L, 
32658L, 32658L, 32658L), min.ts = structure(c(1550365487.1678, 
1550370468.9215, 1550370959.4605, 1550371308.3559, 1550828338.2987, 
1551404901.2144, 1551461336.5935), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), max.ts = structure(c(1550365672.4627, 1550370567.03, 
1550371242.881, 1550371449.99, 1550828501.8146, 1551404988.4236, 
1551461663.6323), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
)), min.lat = c(-4.6888, -4.6888, -4.6888, -4.6888, -4.6888, 
-4.6888, -4.6888), min.lon = c(-37.3581, -37.3581, -37.3581, 
-37.3581, -37.3581, -37.3581, -37.3581), max.lat = c(-4.6888, 
-4.6888, -4.6888, -4.6888, -4.6888, -4.6888, -4.6888), max.lon = c(-37.3581, 
-37.3581, -37.3581, -37.3581, -37.3581, -37.3581, -37.3581), 
    gap.dur = c(16340.5381999016, 4796.45880007744, 0, 0, 456888.308700085, 
    576399.399800062, 56348.1698999405), date = structure(c(17944, 
    17944, 17944, 17944, 17949, 17956, 17956), class = "Date"), 
    Date.Start = structure(c(1550275200, 1550275200, 1550275200, 
    1550275200, 1550275200, 1550275200, 1550275200), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), Strategy = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -7L), groups = structure(list(motusTagID = 32658L, 
    .rows = structure(list(1:7), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Description of data:
motusTagID-categorical value (tag identifier)
min.ts-first detection in set of consecutive detections
max.ts last detection in set of consecutive detections
gap.dur- duration of time between min of current ts and lag(ts.max) from row above. I have removed the first day of detections from each tag, as it is unknown exactly when the tag began working, which is why you're seeing a value for gap.dur in the first row.

code:
data gets reduced like this to calculate duration:

```
test.dat<- test.dat %>%
  group_by(motusTagID,date,Strategy,Date.Start) %>%
  summarise_at(c("gap.dur"), sum, na.rm=TRUE) %>%
  mutate(time.TF=(86400-gap.dur))
```

Tried this to expand by tag:

```
test.dat <- test.dat %>%
    group_by(motusTagID) %>%
    summarize(start=min(date),end=max(date)) %>%
    do(data.frame(motusTagID=.$motusTagID, 
    date=seq(.$start,.$end,by="1 day")))
```

desired output:
min.ts                max.ts
2019-02-17 00:00:01   2019-02-17 00:00:01
::all other detections on feb 17th::
2019-02-17 23:59:59   2019-02-17 23:59:59
::filled in dates (gap in detection dates between 17th and 22nd)
2019-02-18 00:00:01   2019-02-18 00:00:01
2019-02-18 23:59:59   2019-02-18 23:59:59
2019-02-19 00:00:01   2019-02-19 00:00:01
2019-02-19 23:59:59   2019-02-19 23:59:59

etc.

Then I will recalculate gap durations for each tag.

I've also tried various iterations of dplyr::expand(), but it won't work because there are multiple rows for each tag.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question, but based on you description I don't really understand what you want to do with the sample data you provided. Maybe you could show the desired result, or explain the transformation step by step and naming the columns.

Comment: Thanks so much fo the input @peter, I added a desired output to the question above and explained the important variables! I originally broke the df into individual dfs for each tagID number, calculated the gaps between detections, and then recombined into one big dataset. But I'm finding gaps in detections from the beginning and end of each day, and for missing days are throwing me off because of the way I'm using lag() to calculate the gaps!

Comment: And the two code blocks are executed after another? And you want to modify the second one? Or do you want to modify the first one to make the second one unnecessary?